# accounting on vSphere/ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm wondering is there a way to do resource accounting on ESXi.

More specifically: we have researchers who want to use a VM to do heavy calculations using a considerable amount of CPU and we'de like to have a way to objectively quantify how much CPU that have used to be able to be able to internally charge them for the CPU they use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How hard would it be for you to have just looked on their web-site? It took about ten key-strokes and three mouse clicks to get to their [Chargeback Manager](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-chargeback/) link. Please try harder next time.

Comment: Thanks Chopper for your "friendly" answer. Of course I googled for this for a while before asking the question. Anyway, I took a look at the product. It does so much more than what I really need and will probably be too expensive for the budget we have. I will check the price. But thanks to the description of the product I realized that I had to google for "resouce metering" instead of "resource accounting". Using "resource metering" I seem to find some other tools that do the job which are maybe useable. Once I have looked into them I will post the results here instead some else needs it.

Comment: @gert_78 - if you'd read what this site is for you'd be aware that it very specifically isn't here for product recommendations - in fact I'm surprised it wasn't shut down immediately because of that.

Comment: I didn't know that. The moderator can delete the message if he wants to.